# Unable to connect to renderer after updating Chrome browser to latest version

Tags: selenium-webdriver, invalidoperationexception

I keep getting this InvalidOperationException after updating Chrome to the latest version.  I'm using Selenium-Webdriver in c#

```
System.InvalidOperationException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (102)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWindow.Maximize()
```

Comment: This is selenium webdriver using C#

Comment: added tags; fixed formatting; included info from comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the chromediver 2.32 and in the release notes there is written that the support is for Chrome v59-61

As browser you have:

Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
So, from ChromeDriver, you should use the 2.33

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using Selenium with VisGrid. You can download the latest ChromeDriver here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

For VisGrid I had to place that file in VisGrid folder under /drivers/chrome